# How to pass a paramater in this sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select  
    CAST(
        CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
            'xs:base64Binary("MA==")'
          , 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
        ) 
        AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    )   ASCIIEncoding
;
```

---

```
Declare @Value nvarchar(10)
set @Value ='MA=='
Select  
    CAST(
        CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
            'xs:base64Binary("@Value")'
          , 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
        ) 
        AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    )   ASCIIEncoding
;
```

getting an error

Comment: **What** error are you getting?

Comment: i think you need to tell whats the error

Comment: I guess you need to use Dynamic SQL http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Declare @Value nvarchar(10)
set @Value ='MA=='
Select  
    CAST(
        CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
            'xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Value"))'
          , 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
        ) 
        AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    )   ASCIIEncoding
;
```